# Confused about IEnumerator interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand how to use the IEnumerator interface and what it is used for. I have a class which implements the IEnumerator interface. A string array is passed to the constructor method.

The problem is when I execute the code then the array is not listed properly. It should be doing it in the order `"ali"`, `"veli"`, `"hatca"` but it’s listed at the console in this order `"veli"`, `"hatca"` and `-1`. I am so confused. What am I doing wrong here? Can you please help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ogr o = new ogr();
    while (o.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Current.ToString());
    }
}

public class ogr: IEnumerator
{
    ArrayList array_ = new ArrayList();
    string[] names = new string[] {
        "ali", "veli", "hatca"
    };

    public ogr()
    {
        array_.AddRange(names);
    }

    public void addOgr(string name)
    {
        array_.Add(name);
    }

    int position;
    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (position >= 0 && position < array_.Count)
            {
                return array_[position];
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (position < array_.Count && position >= 0)
        {
            position++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is quite difficult to grasp at first, but luckily it's an interface you hardly ever use in itself. Instead, you should probably implement [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, the source of your confusion comes from this line from the IEnumerator documentation:

> Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in
>   the collection. The Reset method also brings the enumerator back to
>   this position. After an enumerator is created or the Reset method is
>   called, you must call the MoveNext method to advance the enumerator to
>   the first element of the collection before reading the value of
>   Current; otherwise, Current is undefined.

Your implementation has its current position at 0 initially, instead of -1, causing the strange behavior. Your enumerator begins with Current on the first element instead of being before it.

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty rare for people to use that API directly. More commonly, it is simply used via the `foreach` statement, i.e.

```
foreach(var value in someEnumerable) { ... }
```

where `someEnumerable` implements `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>` or just the duck-typed pattern. Your class `ogr` *certainly* isn't an `IEnumerator`, and shouldn't be made to try to act like one.

If the intend is for `ogr` to be *enumerable*, then:

```
public ogr : IEnumerable {
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return array_.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I suspect it would be better to be `IEnumerable<string>`, though, using `List<string>` as the backing list:

```
public SomeType : IEnumerable<string> {
    private readonly List<string> someField = new List<string>();
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    { return someField.GetEnumerator(); }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { return someField.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```